# Play multiple audio streams in WP7 PhoneGap

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I new to wp7 phonegap environment and I am having issues playing audio files. I am able to play one audio file as many times possible but cant play another audio of different instance, which is a requirement for my on-going project.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a phonegap native sound system

the javascript code for it is

```
src1="sounds/cartoon001.mp3"
src2="sounds/cartoon002.mp3"
var soundObj1 = new Media(src1,onSuccess,onError);
var soundObj2 = new Media(src2,onSuccess,onError);
soundObj1.play();
soundObj2.play();
```

also kindly check that mp3 files are supported in mobile.

you have to write a overriding functions for onSuccess and onnError.

Answer (score 0):

javascript function to play:

```
playAudioFile("spellsound");

function playAudioFile(id){
var s=document.getElementById(id);
    s.play();
}
```

html page`<audio id='m' src='audio/baby/M.mp3'></audio>`
or u can load src to audio tag by id in DOM

Comment: You should provide more of an explanation/info